# How to use Featuretools to create features on new test data?

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering, featuretools

I have used Featuretools to generate features for a single table using a script like this:

```py
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'data')
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'df', dataframe = X, 
                              variable_types=variable_types, index = 'data_index')

for column in X.columns:
    if column != "data_index":
        es = es.normalize_entity(base_entity_id='df', new_entity_id=column, index=column)
    
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es, target_entity="df")
ft.save_features(feature_defs, "feature_definitions.json")
```

How can I use the features in `feature_definitions.json` on a new pandas dataframe?

I know we have to use this api:

```py
saved_features = ft.load_features("feature_definitions.json")
feature_matrix = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(saved_features, es)
```

But I am having difficulties converting the new data into a compatible entityset.

**Note**: I am using Featuretools version `0.11.0`

How can I acheive this?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You have to re-create your EntitySet for the test data, the same way you created it for the train data. Have the same column names, and data types.